# C++ MessageBox character array

Tags: c++, winapi, types, messagebox

I am having difficulties using MessageBox function with variables

I have

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char* filename = argv[0];
   DWORD length = strlen(filename);

   MessageBox(0, TEXT("filename text"), TEXT("length text"), 0); // Works
}
```

But I want to output variables filename and length as:

```
MessageBox(0, filename, length, 0); -- compiler error
```

Function MessageBox has syntax:

```
int WINAPI MessageBox(
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_      UINT uType
);
```

I tried using

```
MessageBox(0, (LPCWSTR)filename, (LPCWSTR)length, 0);
```

but the output is in some kind of hieroglyphs.

Comment: The third argument `lpCaption` is a string, and you are passing an `int` to it (`length`).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `length` is not a string, and only strings can be used. It doesn't help that you try to cast it to a `char*` as then the value of `length` will be taken as a pointer to the string which will cause undefined behavior.

For C++, you can use e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert non-string values to strings, like

```
MessageBox(0, filename, std::to_string(length).c_str(), 0);
```

Note that you must use the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function to get a `char*`.

If you don't have `std::to_string` then you can use e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instead:

```
std::istringstream is;
is << length;
MessageBox(0, filename, is.str().c_str(), 0);
```

If you want a more old-style C solution, then there's [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (or [`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) in Visual Studio):

```
char length_string[20];
_snprintf(length_string, sizeof(length_string), "%ld", length);
MessageBox(0, filename, length_string, 0);
```

Comment: yes I understand what you guys mean, but the problem is that required file type for the function is LPCTSTR, but if I use
MessageBox(0, (LPCTSTR)filename, (LPCTSTR)filename, 0);
it shows the box with some kind of hieroglyphs instead of filename.

Comment: @Winten It all depends on if you have the `_UNICODE` macro defined or not. In this case it seems to be, in which case you should really be using [`_tmain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) and be usint `TCHAR` and `LPCTSTR` everywhere. Also, if `_UNICODE` is defined you want to use `std::iwstringstream`, `std::to_wstring` or `_snwprintf` instead.

Comment: Using `MessageBoxA` will get the version that takes narrow characters

Answer (score -1):

With a C++ win32 project in VS2015 a char array displays in a MessageBox with this code. Include header atlstr.h

```
// open a file in read mode.
ifstream myInfile;

myInfile.open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\CodeOnDesktop\\myTrialMessageBox.txt");

if (myInfile.fail())
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
        L"We have an error trying to open the file myTrialMessageBox.txt",
        L"Opening a file.",
        MB_ICONERROR);
}

char data[200];

// Read the data from the file and display it.
//infile >> data;   // Only gets the first word.

myInfile.getline(data, 100);

//To use CString, include the atlstr.h header.
// Cast array called data to a CString to enable use as MessageBox parameter.

CString cdata = (CString)data;

// or CString cdata = CString(_T("A string"));

MessageBox(NULL,
    cdata,
    L"Opening a file.",
    MB_ICONERROR);

// close the opened file.
myInfile.close();
```

Comment: Does not address the question of how to show an integer in the messagebox